# Unable to decode json using jsonExport and Codeables

Tags: ios, swift

I am trying to parse using decodable but unable to do it

```js
{
  "response": {
    "status": 1,
    "message": "success",
    "detail": {
      "id": 24,
      "user_id": "23b5ec2c-28a2-4559-bb1c-408f04493d19",
      "auth_id": "sensu_5d4959c99e6b7",
      "name": "taimoor",
      "email": "taimoorsd@gmail.com",
      "serial_no": "aa",
      "model_no": "SSSG-G1-3DP",
      "device_token": null,
      "avatar": "NULL",
      "status": 1,
      "created_at": "2019-08-06 10:43:21",
      "updated_at": "2019-08-22 13:43:02",
      "training_log": [],
      "favorites": []
    }
  },
  "error": {
    "status": 0
  }
}

var model = try JSONDecoder().decode(AuthKey.self, from: data)
```

I have made the model using JSONExport

```
AuthKey(error: Optional(NetworkingLayerCodables.Error(status: nil)), response: Optional(NetworkingLayerCodables.Response(detail: Optional(NetworkingLayerCodables.Detail(authId: nil, avatar: nil, createdAt: nil, deviceToken: nil, email: nil, favorites: nil, id: nil, modelNo: nil, name: nil, serialNo: nil, status: nil, trainingLog: nil, updatedAt: nil, userId: nil)), message: nil, status: nil)))
```

Model for Auth Key

```
import Foundation

struct AuthKey : Codable {
    let error : Error?
    let response : Response?
    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case error
        case response
    }
    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let values = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        error = try Error(from: decoder)
        response = try Response(from: decoder)
    }
}
```

Comment: “unable to do it”, how are you unable? If you get an error then add it to your question and also add your implementation of AuthKey

Comment: It doesn't give any error it just doesn't encode into the object

Comment: import Foundation

struct AuthKey : Codable {

 let error : Error?
 let response : Response?


 enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
  case error
  case response
 }
 init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
  let values = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
  error = try Error(from: decoder)
  response = try Response(from: decoder)
 }


}

Comment: You should add that to the question instead

Comment: Since Error is a built in class it is not a good choice of name for your own class/struct

Comment: What do you suggest then which models should i make?

Comment: I just said I think you should chose another name. There is really not enough information here to understand the question and what you mean by “unable to do it”. Are you sure your error handling is correct and that your code runs fine?

Comment: Ok let me try to explain it in a better way

Comment: If `AuthError` (to give it a new name) and `Response` both conform to `Decodable`, then `AuthKey` gets compiler-generated conformance just by adopting `Decodable`. No need for `CodingKeys` (it wasn't doing anything anyway) or implementing `init(decoder:)`

Answer (score 2):

This isn't a complete implementation (`struct Detail {...}` is missing many fields), but you should be able to fill in the gaps for yourself. Be aware that date/time parsing will probably need more attention than I have so far given it here:

```
import Foundation

struct AuthError: Codable {
    let status: Int
}

struct Response: Codable {
    let status: Int
    let message: String
    let detail: Detail
}

struct Detail: Codable {
    let id: Int
    let userId: String
    let createdAt: Date
}

struct AuthKey : Codable {
    let error : AuthError?
    let response : Response?
}

let data = """
{
  "response": {
    "status": 1,
    "message": "success",
    "detail": {
      "id": 24,
      "user_id": "23b5ec2c-28a2-4559-bb1c-408f04493d19",
      "auth_id": "sensu_5d4959c99e6b7",
      "name": "taimoor",
      "email": "taimoorsd@gmail.com",
      "serial_no": "aa",
      "model_no": "SSSG-G1-3DP",
      "device_token": null,
      "avatar": "NULL",
      "status": 1,
      "created_at": "2019-08-06 10:43:21",
      "updated_at": "2019-08-22 13:43:02",
      "training_log": [],
      "favorites": []
    }
  },
  "error": {
    "status": 0
  }
}
""".data(using: .utf8)!

let formatter = DateFormatter()
formatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss"

let decoder = JSONDecoder()
decoder.keyDecodingStrategy = .convertFromSnakeCase
decoder.dateDecodingStrategy = .formatted(formatter)
do {
    let model = try decoder.decode(AuthKey.self, from: data)
} catch {
    // Failed to decode model
}
```

Note the use of `.keyDecodingStrategy = .convertFromSnakeCase` on the decoder which negates the need for any manual `enum CodingKeys {...}`

Comment: You should avoid using `try?` and have some proper error handling instead.

Comment: In production code, I absolutely agree. For demonstrating a concept in a Playground it didn't feel necessary, but I'll make it clear.

Answer (score 0):

```
import Foundation

// MARK: - CustomObject
struct CustomObject: Codable {
    let response: Response
    let error: Error
}

// MARK: - Error
struct CustonError: Codable {
    let status: Int
}

// MARK: - Response
struct Response: Codable {
    let status: Int
    let message: String
    let detail: Detail
}

// MARK: - Detail
struct Detail: Codable {
    let id: Int
    let userID, authID, name, email: String
    let serialNo, modelNo: String
    let deviceToken: JSONNull?
    let avatar: String
    let status: Int
    let createdAt, updatedAt: String
    let trainingLog, favorites: [JSONAny]

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case id
        case userID = "user_id"
        case authID = "auth_id"
        case name, email
        case serialNo = "serial_no"
        case modelNo = "model_no"
        case deviceToken = "device_token"
        case avatar, status
        case createdAt = "created_at"
        case updatedAt = "updated_at"
        case trainingLog = "training_log"
        case favorites
    }
}
```

To read it,

```
let customObject = try? newJSONDecoder().decode(CustomObject.self, from: jsonData)
```